# calculating time taken between dates only during business hours

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to work out the amount of time between two date/times in vb.net to use on an aspx webpage.  I have searched for ages on here and other sources but I am not getting very far.  All the examples i find are PHP or SQL related.

Basically i have the following....

```
Dim StartDateTime As DateTime = #5/27/2013 6:00:00 AM#

Dim FinishDateTime As DateTime = #5/28/2013 10:30:00 AM#

Dim Minutes As Long = DateDiff(DateInterval.Minute, StartDateTime, FinishDateTime, Microsoft.VisualBasic.FirstDayOfWeek.Monday)
```

which works out the minutes between the start and finish.  Problem is I only want it to calculate the time over our set business hours (9-5) so in the example about it should return 9.5 hours or 570 minutes and eventually not calculating any time if the period goes over a weekend.

the start time can be anything (so can fall before or after business hours) and whilst the end time will typically be in business hours, we would have to assume that can be anything too.

I can perhaps achieve this using a huge amount of IF statements, which seems like an inefficent approach I would like to know if anyone had any pointers to get me going in the right direction.

many thanks

Comment: weekend is easy. How about public holidays?

Comment: they would be nice to have in the long term but not critical

Comment: Find how many working minutes are included from the start time to the end of the working day on that day if it is a working day. Similarly for the end time but from the start of the working day on that day if it is a working day. Then find how many whole working days are included in the interval and multiply by the number of working minutes in a day. Add them all together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already have created a function to get a list of working days between 2 dates (inclusive), minus holidays and weekends as follows:

```
Function GetWorkingDates(startDate As Date, endDate As Date, holidayDates As Date()) As List(Of Date)
    If endDate < startDate Then
        Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException("endDate", "Value must be equal or larger than 'startDate' parameter.")
    End If

    Dim listDate As List(Of Date) = Enumerable.Range(0, 1 + CInt((endDate - startDate).TotalDays)).Select(Function(n) startDate.AddDays(n)).ToList

    ' if defined, remove holidays from listDate
    If holidayDates IsNot Nothing Then listDate.RemoveAll(Function(d) holidayDates.Contains(d))

    ' remove weekends as defined below
    Dim weekends As DayOfWeek() = {DayOfWeek.Saturday, DayOfWeek.Sunday}
    listDate.RemoveAll(Function(d) weekends.Contains(d.DayOfWeek))

    Return listDate
End Function
```

To get total hours, I just created a new function to get the total timespan from the result of my existing function above:

```
Function GetTotalWorkingTimeSpan(startDateTime As Date, endDateTime As Date, startWorkTime As TimeSpan, endWorkTime As TimeSpan, holidayDates As Date()) As TimeSpan
    If endDateTime < startDateTime Then
        Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException("endDate", "Value must be equal or larger than 'startDate' parameter.")
    End If

    If endWorkTime < startWorkTime Then
        Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException("endWorkTime", "Value must be equal or larger than 'startWorkTime' parameter.")
    End If

    ' get list of working days minus weekends and holidays
    Dim lstWorkDays As List(Of Date) = GetWorkingDates(startDateTime.Date, endDateTime.Date, holidayDates)

    ' get total minutes by bultiplying total working days and total minutes per day
    Dim totalMinutes As Double = lstWorkDays.Count * (endWorkTime - startWorkTime).TotalMinutes

    ' deduct the first day's hour if occured later than the startWorkTime, only if startDateTime is a working day
    If lstWorkDays.Contains(startDateTime.Date) Then
        Dim minutesOffset As Double = (startDateTime.TimeOfDay - startWorkTime).TotalMinutes
        If minutesOffset > 0 Then totalMinutes -= minutesOffset
    End If

    ' deduct the last day's hour if occured ealier than the endWorkTime, only if endDateTime is a working day
    If lstWorkDays.Contains(endDateTime.Date) Then
        Dim minutesOffset As Double = (endWorkTime - endDateTime.TimeOfDay).TotalMinutes
        If minutesOffset > 0 Then totalMinutes -= minutesOffset
    End If

    Return TimeSpan.FromMinutes(totalMinutes)
End Function
```

Using your data, I created a test console:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim sdt As Date = #5/27/2013 6:00:00 AM#
    Dim edt As Date = #5/28/2013 10:30:00 AM#
    Dim hols() As Date = {} ' add holiday dates here

    Dim lst As List(Of Date) = GetWorkingDates(sdt, edt, Nothing) ' or simply Nothing to not check for holidays
    Console.WriteLine("Num of working days = " & lst.Count)
    Console.WriteLine()

    Console.WriteLine("List of working dates:")
    lst.ForEach(Sub(d) Console.WriteLine("* " & d.ToLongDateString))
    Console.WriteLine()

    Dim totalWorkingTimeSpan As TimeSpan = GetTotalWorkingTimeSpan(sdt, edt, New TimeSpan(9, 0, 0), New TimeSpan(17, 0, 0), hols)
    Console.WriteLine("Total working hours = " & totalWorkingTimeSpan.TotalMinutes & " minutes, or " & totalWorkingTimeSpan.TotalHours & " hours")

    PromptExit()
End Sub
```

Output of console app:

[image]

Comment: Great thanks alot for your suggestions Ill give them ago when i get chance.  Much appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you just work out the amount of time in non-business hours between start and end

So what you do is create a 'table' of non business hours for the date range

Say it was 1/1/2013 08:20 to 3/1/2013 17:30

```
1/1/2013 00:00:00 to 1/1/2013 08:59:59
1/1/2013 17:00:00 to 1/1/2013 23:59:59
2/1/2013 00:00:00 to 1/2/2013 08:59:59
2/1/2013 17:00:00 to 1/2/2013 23:59:59
3/1/2013 00:00:00 to 3/1/2013 08:59:59
3/1/2013 17:00:00 to 3/1/2013 23:59:59
```

Then you replace the first start time and the last end time to get

```
1/1/2013 08:20:00 to 1/1/2013 08:59:59
1/1/2013 17:00:00 to 1/1/2013 23:59:59
2/1/2013 00:00:00 to 1/2/2013 08:59:59
2/1/2013 17:00:00 to 1/2/2013 23:59:59
3/1/2013 00:00:00 to 3/1/2013 08:59:59
3/1/2013 17:00:00 to 3/1/2013 17:30:00
```

The sum of the durations in the above in is the non business hours. So you just subtract it from end - start.

Lots of different ways of doing this. Search on here and you'll find how to do it in SQL with a CTE

Comment: i dont really want to do it in SQL, unless you are saying thats the only/best method

Comment: Neither the only might not be best. However you code it though, the above is usually the way people go.

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished through code. There are some calculations necessary to get the start and end times "normalized" to the working hours, and some additional calculations necessary to determine weekends, but it is a relatively straightforward exercise:

```
    ' Define the start and end hour of the work day
    Const START_HOUR As Integer = 9
    Const FINISH_HOUR As Integer = 17

    Dim StartDateTime As DateTime = #5/27/2013 6:00:00 AM#

    Dim FinishDateTime As DateTime = #5/28/2013 10:30:00 AM#

    If StartDateTime.Hour < START_HOUR Then
        ' If the current hour is less than the start hour, go to the start of the current day
        StartDateTime = New DateTime(StartDateTime.Year, StartDateTime.Month, StartDateTime.Day, START_HOUR, 0, 0)

    ElseIf StartDateTime.Hour > FINISH_HOUR Then
        ' If the current hour is greater than the end hour, go to the start of the next day
        StartDateTime = New DateTime(StartDateTime.Year, StartDateTime.Month, StartDateTime.Day + 1, START_HOUR, 0, 0)

    End If

    If FinishDateTime.Hour < START_HOUR Then
        ' If the current hour is less than the start hour, go back to the end of the previous day
        FinishDateTime = New DateTime(FinishDateTime.Year, FinishDateTime.Month, FinishDateTime.Day - 1, FINISH_HOUR, 0, 0)

    ElseIf FinishDateTime.Hour > FINISH_HOUR Then
        ' If the current hour is greater than the end hour, go to the end hour of the current day
        FinishDateTime = New DateTime(FinishDateTime.Year, FinishDateTime.Month, FinishDateTime.Day, FINISH_HOUR, 0, 0)

    End If

    ' Determine the total number of actual days the date range crosses
    Dim Days = Math.Ceiling(FinishDateTime.Subtract(StartDateTime).TotalDays)

    Dim Weekends As Double

    ' Determine the number of weekends (might need work)
    If FinishDateTime.DayOfWeek > StartDateTime.DayOfWeek Then
        ' I'm sure this needs work
        Weekends = Math.Floor(Days / 7) + 1
    Else
        Weekends = Math.Floor(Days / 7)
    End If

    ' Determine the number of minutes between the start of the work day and the actual start time
    Dim StartMinutesOffset = ((StartDateTime.Hour * 60) + StartDateTime.Minute) - (START_HOUR * 60)
    ' Determine number of minutes between the finish time and the end of the work day
    Dim FinishMinutesOffset = (FINISH_HOUR * 60) - ((FinishDateTime.Hour * 60) + FinishDateTime.Minute)

    ' The number of minutes is the number of days less 2 * the number of weekends less the start time offset less the finish time offset
    Dim TotalMinutes = (Days - (Weekends * 2)) * ((FINISH_HOUR - START_HOUR) * 60) - StartMinutesOffset - FinishMinutesOffset

    Debug.WriteLine(TotalMinutes)
```

Comment: I would favour stepping through every whole day and determining if it is a working day. That would make it easy to incorporate public holidays, possibly through an external file - which could be updated.

Comment: Great thanks alot for your suggestions Ill give them ago when i get chance.  Much appriciated.